# Parsing POSTed multipart/form-data in Rails 4.2

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, post, multipartform-data

I am trying to implement a *simple* AJAX image uploader with multiple selection support using a standard HTML `input` with `type="file"`. The JS uploading code looks like:

```
var files = document.getElementById("txtFiles").files;
var formData = new FormData();

for (var file = 0; file < files.length; file++) {
  formData.append("userimage", files[file], name)
}

//throw up a loading bar while we're uploading
util.loaderShow("Uploading, please wait...");

$.ajax({

  url: '#{upload_alert_image_url}',

  data: formData,
  processData: false,
  contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
  type: 'POST',

  success: function() {
    util.loaderHide();
    alert("Got success!");
    finish_upload();
  },

  error: function(e) {
    util.loaderHide()
    alert("Upload failed: "+e);
  },

  complete: function() {
    util.loaderHide();
  }

})
```

On the Rails side of things, right now `request.body` is simply saved to a temporary file, and inside that temp file is the body of the request from the above JS snippet, as expected.

What is the correct way to get at that data without having to write a multipart/form-data parser myself? Is there a function somewhere that takes this raw data and spits out some sort of hash or array with the included uploads?

I've been Googling and searching SO and Rails docs for an hour or two trying to find an answer. There are a variety of gems that handle file uploading (most of which have way too other cruft I don't want) as well as the `multipart-parser`, and I have checked these out... but given that multipart/form-data is old and useful, I have a hard time believing there isn't in-the-box support someplace I'm not looking. `Rack::Middleware` claims to have an `.extract_multipart` class method, according to its docs, but I can't figure out how to access it.

So... how is one supposed to receive POST'd multipart/form-data?

Thanks

Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of gems that handle this for you, as you've mentioned. The reason they exist is because

1. There isn't anything built in to rails* simplify handling multipart form data
2. Doing it yourself isn't easy

*Rails 5.2 will *finally* introduce ActiveStorage, built-in polish for handling file uploads.

As an aside, file uploads tie up a server process. If the file is large, this could be really painful for other users trying to access your app as they could get timed out. The general consensus is to upload your files client-side to the cloud storage provider of your choice instead of to your rails server. ActiveStorage will support this as well.

Comment: Thanks you. I was hoping to avoid adding yet another dependency to this already-large project, but it looks like it's that, abandoning multipart, or writing my own support.